# Meaning of 人減 when used as a noun

Tags: meaning, nouns

In my studies, I've come across the noun `人減` used in the context of population.

An example would be,

`十一万人減`.

`減る` means to diminish / decrease.

Thus, I hypothesize the meaning of this noun is to express

`population has decreased [to 110 thousand]`.

Is my assumption correct, or is the meaning different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "decrease/drop (of population) by 110 thousand".

"The population has decreased to 110 thousand." is translated as "人口が、11万人にまで減った。" and it means "The current population is 110 thousand".

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question slightly.  My main question is about 人減 and less about the number itself.  What would the meaning be omitting the number?

Comment: ～人減 means "the number of people decreased". If it is used in the context of population, It means "the population of 110 thousand decreased."

Comment: 人減 isn't a word on its own. It's  ~人 + the suffix 減

Comment: @YuuichiTam I'm sorry to say that "110 thousand people decreased" doesn't really make sense. Do you mean "decreased **by** 110 thousand" / "A reduction of/by 110 thousand people"? e.g. If we start with 30 people and then say 10人減 , do we finish with 20 people?  Or do you mean the population started at 110 thousand and decreased to some unspecified number. I hope it's not this second meaning or I'll be really confused.